# min css these two classes & ids

Tags: html, css

What is the minimalist syntax for these two classes?

```
.sortable1Wrapper { width:190px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #eee; float:left; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px }
.sortable2Wrapper { width:190px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #eee; float:left; }
```

What is I style by their ids?

```
.sortable1Wrapper { width:190px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #eee; float:left; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px }
.sortable2Wrapper { width:190px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #eee; float:left; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the minimalist sintax for your two class is

```
.sortable1Wrapper, .sortable2Wrapper { width:190px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #eee; float:left; }
.sortable1Wrapper { margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px }
```

Comment: Is there a milling 'r' in the second line's class?

Comment: @Steve  missing r   .. added .. answer updated .. thanks